# Mask all characters with preg_replace except some needles

Tags: php, regex

With PHP preg_replace and regex

```
$string_1 = "leave sb. alone";
$string_2 = "pick one's way forward";
$string_2 = "suffer from sth.";
```

i need to mask each string with a specified character but leave the spaces, apostrophe and some string untouched, like:

```
$mask_1 = "XXXXX sb. XXXXX";
$mask_2 = "XXXX XXX'X XXX XXXXXXX";
$mask_2 = "XXXXXX XXXX sth.";
```

In this case i want to keep: sb. sth. spaces and apostrophe.
Any help would be much appreciated.

with `$mask_1 = preg_replace('/(sb.\K)?./s', 'X', $string_1);` i only leave the 'sb.' but spaces still changing.

PS: Both @Casimir et Hippolyte & @Wiktor Stribiżew answers are great solutions but i accepted Wiktor's for the SKIP-FAIL implementation and explanation. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, fine. So what is your question? You obviously want to replace all characters except some specific ones and some phrases. Do it.

Comment: @arkascha thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use SKIP-FAIL regex:

```
'~(?:s(?:b|th)\.|[\s'])(*SKIP)(*F)|.~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aTZ2IF/1)

**Details**:

- `(?:s(?:b|th)\.|[\s'])` - match `s` and then either `b` (`sb`) or `th` (`sth`), then `.` or whitespace or `'` (`[\s']`)
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - omit the match, and go looking for the next match from the end of the matched text
- `|` - or
- `.` - match a char other than a linebreak char (add DOTALL modifier to also match line break chars)

If you need to match whole words that you want to keep, do not forget to add word boundaries, `\b` (e.g. `'~(?:\bs(?:b|th)\.|[\s'])(*SKIP)(*F)|.~'`).

Comment: Thank you and for the great explanation as well. Can you let me know how can i add also the "sb.'s" exception?

Comment: Add it as an alternative, or add as an optional part for matching `sb`: [`'~(?:\bs(?:b\.(?:'s)?|th\.)|[\s'])(*SKIP)(*F)|.~'`](https://regex101.com/r/KI2r8G/2) or [`(?:\bsb\.(?:'s)?|\bsth\.|[\s'])(*SKIP)(*F)|.`](https://regex101.com/r/KI2r8G/3).

Answer (score 1):

You can test this one that targets the characters you want:

```
(?:\G|\b(?!sb\.|sth\.))[[:alnum:]]
```

*(you can also change `[[:alnum:]]` to `\w` or `[^\W_]`)*

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/s2d6ZD/1)

or this one that skips using `\K` the characters you don't want:

```
\G(?:\W*(?:\bs(?:b|th)\.)?)*+\K.
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/s2d6ZD/4)

In the two patterns, `\G` ensures the contiguity.

Comment: Thanks, looks great at the regex101.com but i cannot manage to embed into php preg_replace. Please advise.

Comment: @Karls: regex101 has a code generator feature, click the link to see what you have missed. the delimiters perhaps?

Comment: `$mask_1 = preg_replace('/\G(?:\W*(?:\bs(?:b|th)\.)?)*+\K./gs', 'X', $string_1);`

Comment: @NicolasMaltais: Yes without the g.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte Ok, found it, Fantastic, thank you! Now its works.
Is there any easy way to add more exception to the regex, like: "sb.'s"?

Comment: @Karls: You can add it using the same way: `\G(?:\W*(?:\b(?:sb\.'|sth\.|sb\.))?)*+\K.`. You can also store all your exceptions in an array, and build your pattern dynamically using `array_map`, `preg_quote` and `implode`.